# how to plot 23h-25h time-series in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this kind of table.

[image]

I want to plot x=day, y=hour (x-y graph) on one graph.

so I set all days into certain fixed day(2017-03-01) except hour and minute parameters for plot.

and after plot graph, I just change x label from original time data

accordingly this steps i get the graph as bellow.

[image]

but a problem occurs in 23~00 hours data

[image]

in order to look clear in graph

If the gap of minimum and maximum is over 23 hours,

I want to search all 00:00 time-slot in dataframe and add at 00:00 to 24 hours

Autually, there is an hour difference from 23:00 to 24:00.

But, the difference of below graph I attached from 23:00 to 00:00 is 23 hours.

Could you please let me know how to plot the data as I requested?

I also attach my code too

```
plt.clf()
#####read files###########################
df = pd.read_excel('files',parse_dates=[0])
#####to make xlabel###########################
x = range(len(df))
xla =df['UTC'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#####set the days same date ###########################
y = df['UTC'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=2020, month=3, day=1))
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(x, y ,marker='s', color='k')

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(interval=5))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
plt.xticks(x,xla)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
plt.title('time_of_waypoint', fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('day')
plt.ylabel('time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""datetime
2018-04-03 00:00:00
2018-04-04 23:56:00
2018-04-05 23:57:00
2018-04-06 23:58:00
2018-04-07 00:02:00
2018-04-08 23:59:00
2018-04-09 23:57:00
2018-04-10 23:52:00
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, engine='python')
df['datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
x = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%m-%d'))
y = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%H:%m'))

plt.plot(x,y, 'o')
plt.plot(x,y, '-')
plt.xlabel('month-day')
plt.ylabel('hour:minute')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank u for your kindly comment but i'd like to plot time data range in 23~25 to show easily . is there any method how to plot 23~25 range of time ?

Comment: @HG.KIM what you mean by `23-25`?

Comment: i mean 23:00 to 25:00hours  not 00:00 to 23:59

Comment: @HG.KIM you data don't contain any records with range 24-25h. What you mean by 25h? data from next day?

Comment: i want to convert 00:00 to 24:00 to show easily. for instance in my data 00:03:00 into 24:03:00, 00:00:00 into 24:00:00 and so on